# Kubernetes RBAC cluster-admin without secret reading permission

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Is it possible to create a Kubernetes cluster admin without the ability to read namespace secrets?

I know you can create a ClusterRole and list every single resource and omit secret but seems unintuitive.

Can you use Aggregated ClusterRoles to remove a permission? so using ClusterRole cluster-admin and have a role that uses:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: [""]
```

Comment: you can create a custom role that dont have access to reading secrets , but admin is not admin if doesnt have access to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really [`Aggregated Cluster Roles`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#aggregated-clusterroles) is a [set union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) of several `ClusterRole`s. To get the behavior you want you would need a [set subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of cluster-admin role minus the rules that you have defined. [It's not supported in K8s as of this writing](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70387).